# What is the code to tell a Lambda@Edge function to do a redirect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So just to be clear I have spent several hours googling things and none of these work. This is not a "low effort post".

This is an example of the code I have been trying. It doesn't work. Neither does doing response like this `response.headers=[{Location:"foo"}]` or `response.headers=[{location:"foo"}]` or the other eight ways I've tried it.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    if(request.uri === "/") {
    var response = {
        statusCode: 301,
        headers: {
            "location" : [{
                key: "Location",
                value: "foo"
            }]
        },
        body: null
    };
    callback(null, response);
}
```

I've tried the following links:

- http://blog.ryangreen.ca/2016/01/04/how-to-http-redirects-with-api-gateway-and-lambda/
- http://blog.rowanudell.com/redirects-in-serverless/
- https://kennbrodhagen.net/2016/04/02/how-to-return-302-using-api-gateway-lambda/
- [Python AWS Lambda 301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064735/python-aws-lambda-301-redirect)
- http://www.davekonopka.com/2016/serverless-aws-lambda-api-gateway.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mentioned the link to this example in your question; it should work with Lambda Proxy Integration:

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
var response = {
    statusCode: 301,
    headers: {
        "Location" : "http://example.com"
    },
    body: null
};
callback(null, response);
};
```

source: http://blog.ryangreen.ca/2016/01/04/how-to-http-redirects-with-api-gateway-and-lambda/

## Update:

Else, try using this example from [this page of example functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html):

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
/*
 * Generate HTTP redirect response with 302 status code and Location header.
 */
const response = {
    status: '302',
    statusDescription: 'Found',
    headers: {
        location: [{
            key: 'Location',
            value: 'http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html',
        }],
    },
};
callback(null, response);
};
```

Comment: that's literally the fist url in the list of urls i said I tried. do you have any knowledge about this? I am not providing an absolute url so maybe that's it. Although if I remember correctly the error message with that code is something about headers needs to be an array. ...that code you linked to is the first thing i tried. im not sure if your response is a joke.

Comment: Yes, but are you using it with Lambda Proxy Integration?

Comment: The lambda is triggered from View Request and Origin Request triggers on cloudfront. I dont even know what the API Gateway API is.

Comment: Hmm. Have you taken a look at the example on [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html) of the AWS docs? (see the section with the header "Example: Generating an HTTP Redirect (Generated Response)"

Comment: I have tried several of the examples on that page but forgot to include it in the list. I've tried that exact code and it said something about permissions. Let me try it again. It will take about twenty minutes before I know if it worked. Thanks for digging that up. ...im just going to use the full url this time too.

Comment: @Tyrsius I went and looked up the actual code I ended up using. Quick side note (sorry), I've had some really bad experiences with AWS. If I need a cloud service provider again I'll use something else. `function redirect(url, callback) {
    const response = {
        status: '302',
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
            location: [{
                key: 'Location',
                value: url,
            }],
        },
    };
    callback(null, response);
}`. Let me know if you need more code or context.

Comment: `exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const lastPost = 3;
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const host = `http://${request.headers.host[0].value}`;
    
    if(request.uri === "/") {
        request.uri = `/index.html`; 
    }
    else if(request.uri.endsWith("/")){
        let noSlash = request.uri.replace(/^\//, "").replace(/\/$/, "");
        redirect(`${host}/${noSlash}`, callback);
        return;
    }...callback(null, request);`